# $E [Z(u) \overline{Z(v)}]=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} E [Z_N(u) \overline{Z_N(v)}]=\int\sum_n f_n(t) \overline{f_n(s)} u(t) \overline{v(s)} d u d s$?

Tags: stochastic-processes

A stochastic process $\{Z(t), t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is called a generalized stationary Gaussian process with mean $0$ and covariance $\{\gamma(s), s \in \mathbb{R}\}$ if for every test function $u(t)$, the random variable $Z(u)$ is normal with mean $0$, and if, for two test functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$, the covariance of the random variables $Z(u)$ and $Z(v)$ equals
$$
\Gamma(u, v)=E \left[ Z(u) \overline{Z(v)} \right] =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t) \overline{v(s)} \gamma(t-s) d t d s .
$$
Here $\gamma(t)$ may be a distribution (or generalized function). One writes informally $E Z(t) \overline{Z(s)}=$ $\gamma(t-s)$. For example, if $Z$ is white noise $(H=1 / 2)$, then $\gamma$ is the Dirac $\delta$ generalized function $(<\delta, u>=u(0))$ and $\Gamma(u, v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t) \bar{v}(t) d t$.

I am reading the paper titled [Wavelets, generalized white noise and fractional integration: The synthesis of fractional Brownian motion](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01261639), where I found in the proof of Proposition 1, the following argument:

> If $\epsilon_n, n \geq 0$ are i.i.d. with mean zero and unit variance and if $f_0(t), \ldots, f_n(t), \ldots$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
> $$
> Z(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t) \epsilon_n
> $$
> converges almost surely as a generalized function, then $E \left[ Z(t) \overline{Z(s)} \right] =\delta(t-s)$, that is, the limit is a generalized white noise. Indeed, if $Z_N(t)=\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(t) \epsilon_n$, then for any two test functions $u$ and $v$,
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> E \left[ Z(u) \overline{Z(v)} \right] & =\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} E \left[ Z_N(u) \overline{Z_N(v)} \right] \\ & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t) \overline{f_n(s)} u(t) \overline{v(s)} \ d u d s \\
> & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overline{f_n(s) v(s)} d s\right) d t \\
> & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t) \overline{\langle f_n, v \rangle}\right) d t \\
> & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t) \overline{v(t)} d t .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> In the last steps there are few things that I can't understand.

I can't explain the first two equalities, i.e. I can't explain why $$E \left[ Z(u) \overline{Z(v)} \right] =\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} E \left[ Z_N(u) \overline{Z_N(v)} \right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t) \overline{f_n(s)} u(t) \overline{v(s)} \ d u d s.$$

**Edit**

Since $Z(u)=\langle Z, u\rangle=\langle \sum_n f_n \epsilon_n, u\rangle=\sum_n \epsilon_n\langle f_n , u\rangle$, we have that
$$\langle Z(u), Z(v) \rangle=  \langle \sum_n \epsilon_n \langle f_n , u\rangle, \sum_m \epsilon_m \langle f_m , v\rangle \rangle$$
(in the last formula the brackets are related to the expectation and are different from those that define $Z(u)$ as a generalized process). Hence
$$\langle Z(u), Z(v) \rangle= \sum_n \langle f_n , u\rangle  \sum_m \overline{\langle f_m , v\rangle} \langle  \epsilon_n ,  \epsilon_m  \rangle$$
Since $\{\epsilon_n\}$ are i.i.d. with mean zero and unit variance, we have that
$$\langle Z(u), Z(v) \rangle= \sum_n \langle f_n , u\rangle  \overline{\langle f_n , v\rangle}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors are using that the limit

$$
Z(u) = \lim_{N\to\infty}Z_N(u)
$$

converges not just almost-surely, but also in $L^2(\mathbb P)$. To see this, note that for $M \ge N,$

$$
E\lvert Z_M(u) - Z_N(u) \rvert^2 = E\left\lvert\sum_{n=N+1}^M \langle f_n, u \rangle\epsilon_n\right\rvert^2=\sum_{n=N+1}^M \lvert\langle f_n, u \rangle\rvert^2\le\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \lvert\langle f_n, u \rangle\rvert^2\to 0
$$
as $N \to \infty$, since $u \in L^2(\mathbb R)$, and the $f_n$ are an orthonormal basis. Thus the sequence $Z_N(u)$ is Cauchy in $L^2(\mathbb P)$, so has an $L^2(\mathbb P)$-limit $\tilde Z(u)$, which must coincide with the almost-sure limit $Z(u)$.

Writing $\langle X, Y \rangle = E[X\overline{Y}]$ also for the inner product on $L^2(\mathbb P)$, we then have that
$$
\langle Z(u), Z(v) \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle Z_N(u), Z_N(v) \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f_n, u \rangle \overline{\langle f_n, v \rangle} = \langle u, v \rangle.
$$
using the continuity of the inner product, and that the $f_n$ are an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Edit: The first equality in the final display holds because $Z_N(u) \to Z(u)$ in $L^2(\mathbb P)$, $Z_N(v) \to Z(v)$, and the inner product of an $L^2$ space is continuous. The second equality holds for sums up to any finite $N$ by linearity of the inner product, so it must hold also in the limit $N \to \infty$. The third equality holds because $f_n$ is an orthonormal basis, so $u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f_n, u \rangle f_n$, $v=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f_n, v \rangle f_n$, and we can argue as in the first two equalities.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer. I understand the argument on the convergence of $Z_N$. What I do not understand are the steps contained in the following formula:
$\langle Z(u), Z(v) \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle Z_N(u), Z_N(v) \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f_n, u \rangle \overline{\langle f_n, v \rangle} = \langle u, v \rangle.$ I tried to explain them in my original question. Let me know if I made some mistakes please.

Comment: Hi @Lely; I think you get the idea, though your final formula should sum over $m = n$, not $n$ and $m$ separately, and I'd maybe say more about why you can interchange limits and inner products. I've edited the answer to add more detail on those steps.